# pythonTeX not printing variable in pycode environment

Tags: pythontex

I'm trying to print the value of str from the pycode environment, however, it doesn't work. Interestingly `\pyc{print(str)}` works. Can someone please show me how to get the pycode environment to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\setstring}[1]{\pyc{str="#1"}}

\begin{document}
\setstring{hello pluto}

The value of str is:
\begin{pycode}
  print(str)
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run a second pass, after you compile it  with pythontex, like this

```
pdflatex foo.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py  foo.tex
pdflatex foo.tex
```

Now it should show up.

Change the path to `pythontex.py` as need per your installation